# Count lines crossing raster cells with R

Tags: r, raster

I have the following raster (shp file using `readORG`):

```
dput(summary_grid)
structure(list(class = structure("SpatialPolygonsDataFrame", package = "sp"), 
    bbox = structure(c(4346000, 3819000, 4445000, 3867000), .Dim = c(2L, 
    2L), .Dimnames = list(c("x", "y"), c("min", "max"))), is.projected = TRUE, 
    proj4string = "+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs", 
    data = structure(c("Min.   :0  ", "1st Qu.:0  ", "Median :0  ", 
    "Mean   :0  ", "3rd Qu.:0  ", "Max.   :0  "), .Dim = c(6L, 
    1L), .Dimnames = list(c("", "", "", "", "", ""), "      Id"), class = "table")), .Names = c("class", 
"bbox", "is.projected", "proj4string", "data"), class = "summary.Spatial")
```

as well as the shp file containing lines:

```
dput(summary_lines)
structure(list(class = structure("SpatialLinesDataFrame", package = "sp"), 
    bbox = structure(c(4329488.96922647, 3429159.10800761, 4998503.48859431, 
    4055688.10547651), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("x", 
    "y"), c("min", "max"))), is.projected = TRUE, proj4string = "+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs", 
    data = structure(c("Min.   :0  ", "1st Qu.:0  ", "Median :0  ", 
    "Mean   :0  ", "3rd Qu.:0  ", "Max.   :0  ", "Min.   :  448  ", 
    "1st Qu.:13229  ", "Median :28235  ", "Mean   :27205  ", 
    "3rd Qu.:40724  ", "Max.   :50608  ", "Min.   :  485  ", 
    "1st Qu.:13731  ", "Median :29399  ", "Mean   :28635  ", 
    "3rd Qu.:43159  ", "Max.   :53607  ", "Min.   :6519754  ", 
    "1st Qu.:8741416  ", "Median :9167928  ", "Mean   :8894830  ", 
    "3rd Qu.:9414708  ", "Max.   :9762259  ", "Fishing:121  ", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = c(6L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(c("", 
    "", "", "", "", ""), c("      Id", "   trip_id", "  new_tr_id", 
    "     species", "  HELCOM_Gro")), class = "table")), .Names = c("class", 
"bbox", "is.projected", "proj4string", "data"), class = "summary.Spatial")
```

In this shp file with the lines, each lines has a unique identification number called new_tr_id.

My goal is to create a raster file with the number if lines crossing each cell. A line (so the same new_tr_id) can cross the same cell X times, it would be counted X times. I added the figure below as example:

[image: In red are the values for each cell. I added the new_tr_id for each line to understand the counting method. For example in the cell surrounded with the blue color, the value is 2 because the lines with the new_tr_id 3 is crossing 2 times]

I have some interesting discussions using the package `raster` but I still can not find a proper answer to this issue.

Help is more than welcome :)

Comment: I have tried ´rasterize(lines, test_grid, fun = "count") ´but it is counting for each line. For example if a line is crossing 2 times a cell, the value is still 1 but not 2 (cf. the blue highlight on my figure).

Answer (score 0):

That is tricky. Counting is standard, and counting the total length is not [that hard](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119993/convert-line-shapefile-to-raster-value-total-length-of-lines-within-cell/120175). But I think I come with something.

Example data

```
library(raster)
cds1 <- rbind(c(-180,-20), c(-140,55), c(10, 0), c(-140,-60))
cds2 <- rbind(c(-10,0), c(140,60), c(160,0), c(140,-55))
cds3 <- rbind(c(-125,0), c(0,60), c(40,5), c(15,-45))
lns <- spLines(cds1, cds2, cds3, crs="+proj=utm +zone=1 +datum=WGS84")   
r <- raster(ncols=9, nrows=5, vals=1:45, crs="+proj=utm +zone=1 +datum=WGS84")
```

Standard count:

```
x <- rasterize(lns, r, fun='count')
```

We can break the line segments up by the raster cell borders (this will not work for very large rasters).

```
rsp <- rasterToPolygons(r)
lns2 <- intersect(lns, rsp)
r <- rasterize(lns2, r, fun='count')
```

But the result is not correct because if a segment touches a cell, it is counted as in.

So another approach would be to cut them and remove just a little at the edges. There are two parameters that you will have to play with for your data

```
wdth = .25
smallp = 100
b <- buffer(rsp, dissolve=FALSE, width=wdth)
j <- intersect(b, b)
j$area <- area(j)
small <- j[j$area < smallp, ]
small <- aggregate(small)
lns3 <- erase(lns, small)

r <- rasterize(lns3, r, fun='count')
plot(r)
lines(rsp)
plot(lns, col=rainbow(3), lwd=2, add=T)
```

Quite a work around, but the result looks good.

[image: R plot]

Comment: Thanks for the idea @RobertH. Unfortunately my dataset is big but I had a look at your approach. When I run ´j <- intersect(b, b)`, it says `Error in as.vector(y) : no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector`. Do you have the same error?

Comment: You are calling `base::intersect` instead of `raster::intersect`; perhaps inside of a package? Either way, make it explicit by using `raster::intersect` instead or just `instersect`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this same process using sf geometry instead of sp? I tried with grid sf and it doesn't run.